# What happens when returning from a for...on loop with ES7 async and an async generator function?

Tags: javascript, traceur, ecmascript-next

I am trying to rack my brains around what happens in the following example:

```
class Project {
  async foo(input) {
    for (let barOutput on this.bar(input)) {
      // what happens on the following line?
      return barOutput.id;
    }
  }

  async *bar(input) {
    yield {
      id: input.id,
      title: "Test"
    };
  }
}

new Project().foo()
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Does the `return` statement inside the `for...of` loop unsubscribe from the observer that represents the output of `Project#bar`?

Comment: @Tushar it seems to require `for...on` with this use case; `for...of` just reports an error; whereas `for...on` actually works; but I want to learn a little about the internals.

Comment: @Tushar if you select 'Experimental' mode under 'Options' on the [Traceur Transcoding Demo](http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html) page you can see that `for...on` works here.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any documentation on `for...on`. Could you please add some reference?